# WinForms HelpProvider. Is it possible to open HTML file with additional parameters?

Tags: c#, html, .net, winforms

I have index.html file and if i start this page with # page open specific part of page. Is it possible to start index.html# in HelpProvider from WinForms?
If i try to do this the with HelpNamespace = "/index.html#" exception occurs.

Comment: Unsure about `HelpProvider` but for CHM help files, the call would look like, `System.Windows.Forms.Help.ShowHelp(parentControl, "MainHelp.chm", HelpNavigator.Topic, "SomePage.html#SomeBookmark");`

Comment: Change format of help can be a problem for me, so i looking for another solution